# Error with query after changing database compatibility from 2000 to 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, compatibility

This query works fine before changing SQL Compatibility Level from 80(2000) to 100(2008).  It is now failing after changing to Compatibility Level 100 (2008):

```
WITH NanMckay AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        {large select statement}
)
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY client) 'Count', *  
FROM 
    NanMcKay
ORDER BY 
    client
```

The goal is to get a result with a row number in the first column. I attempted to change it to the following, but the nature of the data behind the query generated many duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY osentity.entityid) 'Count',
    ...{large select statement}
```

It was because of all these duplicates that we used the original method, but now that syntax is incompatible with 2008 compatibility level.

Any idea how to change the syntax of the original method so that we can avoid the duplicates?

Comment: what is the original query?

Comment: Is impossible that the query worked fine in SQL Server 2000 because `ROW_NUMBER()`  and common table expressions were added in SQL Server 2005. Maybe you want to say that it worked in SQL 2008 but doesn't works after changing compatibility to 80/SQL Server 2000?

Comment: We have been using SQL 2008 for many years.  The database in question was at Compatibility Level 80 (2000) up until a couple weeks ago.  We performed an upgrade to the system that uses that database that required the database to be at Compatibility Level 100 (2008) or higher.  After we did this, we are now unable to execute the query.

Comment: and what exactly the error you are encountering? you may also share the error message.

Comment: The error we are receiving:  Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Did you terminate the previous statement with a semicolon?